# Windows Batch Scripting : Regular Expression Or Statement

Tags: regex, windows, batch-file

```
@echo off
set out=%~dp0\FileName.txt
(for /r %~dp0 %%F in ((*System1*.txt*) | (*System2*.txt*)) do (if %%~zF GEQ 1 echo %%F)) > %out% 
exit /b
```

I am trying with the above batch file to look at the directory the batch file is in for files containing a certain string and there size is over 0KB.

The problem I am having is with the OR statement.

Comment: Explain a little more.  All files are over zero bytes, and what are you trying to do with them?

Comment: Windows command line doesn't have regular expressions in the way you are using them so you'll have to reveal the details of the task to get an appropriate solution.

Comment: I want all files greater than 0kb to be written out to a text file called FileName.txt.

Comment: Is there a way to just exclude this Filename.txt file, but still return all other files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Batch file below fulfills your specifications:

```
@echo off
set out=%~dp0\FileName.txt

rem "am trying with this batch file to look at the directory the batch file is in"
(for /r "%~dp0" %%F in (*System1*.txt* *System2*.txt*) do (
   rem "I want all files greater than 0kb to be written out"
   if %%~zF GEQ 1 (
      rem "Is there a way to just exclude this Filename.txt file?"
      if "%%~nxF" neq "Filename.txt" echo %%F
   )
)) > "%out%"
exit /b
```

However, you must note the following points:

- The path to the batch file (`%~dp0`) should be enclosed in quotes in case it may include spaces.
- If there are no other files with `System`, just the desired `System1` or `System2`, then `(*System*.txt*)` wild-card would be enough.
- Usually all files have a size greater than zero bytes. If your system does not regularly create empty files, the related `if` command is not necessary.
- The output filename `Filename.txt` will never match the given `*System*.txt*` wild-card, so the last `if` command is not necessary.

Comment: This code generates a text file even if nothing is written to it. Is there a way to make it not generate a file or delete it in some way?

Comment: @dog2bert: Insert this line at end: `for %%a in ("%out%") do if %%~Za equ 0 del "%out%"`

Answer (score 0):

Without further details this is a possible solution using your code as a base:

```
@echo off
set "out=%~dp0\FileName.txt"
(for /r "%~dp0" %%F in (*System*.txt*) do if %%~zF GTR 0 echo %%F)>"%out%"
exit /b
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
    set "out=%~dp0FileName.txt"
    (for /r "%~dp0" %%F in (*System1*.txt* *System2*.txt*) do if %%~zF GEQ 1 echo %%F) > %out% 
    exit /b
```

`for` command allow multiple sets of files in the `in` clause, so, just include them.